# KML file from Massachusetts GIS - display in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I've been pulling KML files from the Mass GIS service via their export feature:
http://maps.massgis.state.ma.us/map_ol/oliver.php

For example, a KML output of Population Density per Square Mile looks like this when exported:
http://evrkusd.fatcow.com/populationpersquaremile.kml

I try to add it to my Google Map and nothing shows up, although this code works fine with other kml files from other sources.
`var NewLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://evrkusd.fatcow.com/populationpersquaremile.kml');
    NewLayer.setMap(map);`

I'm getting the idea that some of the kml tags are outdated or are not accepted by Google Maps API.

Is anyone able to get this file to work for them? Any ideas how I can (preferably easily) update this file to work with Google Maps? I'm going to be using multiple KML files like this, so I'm hoping I can do a fairly quick fix.

Comment: Something to note - it shows up when loaded into Google Earth, but doesn't show when loaded through Google Maps API

Comment: Additional note - the original file was too large, but I split it into two files, so this is no longer a possible source of the overall issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your KML file is still too big:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/populationpersquaremile.kml

If you click on the "load KmlLayer" button, it will show you the status return by attempting to load that file in KmlLayer:

Kml Status:DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE

Your "partial" KML files are not valid xml, if I make the one you posted [valid](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/evrkusd_Pop1a.kml), [it works with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/evrkusd_Pop1a.kml), but the Google Maps API v3 KmlLayer still says it is too big.

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport), the maximum fetched size of a raw KML file is 3M, your file is 7M+.

Comment: The file I have linked is too big, but  I've tried it split into two as well. I think the formatting is the issue, not the size. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't tell you without seeing the files.  You could attempt to load it into FusionTables, but might be too big for that also (although per @rob-mcchesney that might work).  You can display it with a third party parser (like I did with geoxml3), but that will be slower than using either KmlLayer or FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: evrkusd.fatcow.com/Pop1.kml is one of the two files. I tried importing into fusion tables and am unable to get anything useable out of it.

Comment: Chrome doesn't think [your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/evrkusd_Pop1.xml) is valid XML: `This page contains the following errors:
error on line 3 at column 29: Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation on Document is not defined`, neither does Firefox: `XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
Location: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/evrkusd_Pop1.xml
Line Number 3, Column 1:<Document xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd">
^`

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables can handle much larger KML than client-side maps, up 100MB total (though some limits apply to features). So that might be a solution.